# Install extension from a specific repo/branch on GitHub?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using a VS Code extension that has a bug. It has been fixed in a pull request on GitHub, but the repository seems to be abandoned and the PR is not getting merged.

How do I install an extension directly from a specific repo/branch on GitHub?

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world for how to build and install extensions

Answer (score 59):

- [Install vsce](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#installation):

  > Make sure you have Node.js installed. Then run:
  >
  > ```
  > npm install -g vsce
  > ```
- Check out the GitHub repo/branch you want.
- Depending on the project, you may need to install its dependencies (`npm install` or whatever package manager you use). Some can be packaged without dependencies.
- Run the following in the root of the project (see the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#packaging-extensions) for more detail about the process):

  ```
  vsce package  # Generates a .vsix file
  code --install-extension my-extension-0.0.1.vsix
  ```

Comment: At which step do I specify repo and branch of the extention I want to.install?

Comment: @AndreyMikhaylov-lolmaus I just updated my answer. You don't specify it anywhere, you simply check out the code and run vsce in that project.

Comment: Ah, you mean install it locally?

Comment: What do you mean? That was your question was? "How do I install an extension directly from a specific repo/branch on GitHub?"

Comment: I'm asking if `vsce` or `code` allow installing from GitHub similar to how npm does: `npm add my-org/my-repo#my-branch`

Comment: This solution helped me, thanks ! May I suggest to add the `npm install` command after the `git clone` and before the `vsce package` package to generate the `node_module` directory ?

Comment: @Muldec Good idea, I've updated my solution accordingly.

Comment: I ended up here from a different need/issue but your "vsce package" solved the issue I was stuck on - thanks!